# How to return Collection subtype instead of abstract Collection?

Tags: java, list, generics, collections, set

Say I have a (simplified) generic utility method:

```java
public Collection<T> returnExample(Collection<T> col) {

    return col;
}
```

If I give it a list, is there a way to get it to return a list, rather than a collection?
Similarly if I give it a set, how can it return a set?

Answer (score 0):

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList<Double> list = returnExample(List.of(1.1, 2.1, 44.2));
    HashSet<String> set = returnExample(Set.of("aaa", "bbb", "ccc"));

    System.out.println(list); // [1.1, 2.1, 44.2]
    System.out.println(set);  // [bbb, aaa, ccc]
}
```

```java
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public static <U, T extends Collection<U>> T returnExample(Collection<U> col) {
    if (col instanceof Set)
        return (T) new HashSet<U>(col);
    else
        return (T) new ArrayList<U>(col);
}
```